# Apache Weblogic Ifmodule without location

Tags: apache, weblogic

I have this configuration for apache-weblogic bridge:

```
"<VirtualHost *:80>

<IfModule mod_weblogic.c>
    SetHandler weblogic-handler
    WebLogicCluster XXXXXX:7002,XXXXXXX:7003
</IfModule>

</VirtualHost>"
```

All go to weblogic... but i have a control file in / of DocumentRoot, it have to be serve with apache, ¿How can i do it?.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You could put it in a `<Location>` block to say what should be forwarded to Weblogic.

```
<Location /weblogic>
 SetHandler weblogic-handler
</Location>
```

This would forward everything under `/weblogic` to `Weblogic` and the rest should be served by the `Apache` server.

More useful examples can be found at [oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/plugins/apache.html#119517). Hope it helps you forward.